# How to set drawable on ImageView in Service Class in Android

Tags: android, service, imageview, drawable

Trying to set a drawable on an imageview in my Service class, but I can't find the drawable I imported. I can set it fine in Activity class though. Is there a particular way to do this inside Service class?

```
class FloatingVoiceService: Service() {

private var windowManager: WindowManager? = null
private var floatingVoiceDrawable: ImageView? = null
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    floatingVoiceDrawable = ImageView(this)
    floatingVoiceDrawable!!.setImageResource(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, 
    R.drawable.ic_record_voice_over_black_24dp))
}
```

R.drawable.ic_record_voice_over_black_24dp is underlined red as the IDE can't find it

Comment: Did you import your R class properly?

Comment: Yep R class is imported

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can NOT access your UI/Main thread directly from any other thread.

You can use :
**runOnUiThread()**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29